# Translating in html templates using i18n

Tags: magento2, i18n

I'm using i18n to translate some values in html static templates (default.html):

So this does not work:

```
<!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type != 'file') -->
    <span data-bind="i18n: option.value"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

But if I add the translation to all the "option.value" possible values, the "option.value" is correctly translated:

```
<!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type != 'file') -->
    <span style="display: none;" data-bind="i18n: 'Value 1'"></span>
    <span style="display: none;" data-bind="i18n: 'Value 2'"></span>
    <span style="display: none;" data-bind="i18n: 'Value 3'"></span>
    <span data-bind="i18n: option.value"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If the option value is on of the values ("Value 1", "Value 2" and "Value 3") it is correctly translated. Help please !!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do something like this

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml#L16

So something like this

```
data-bind="text: new String('Translate: %1!', '%1').replace('%1', option.value)">
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving you any feedback, I'll try this out on Monday and will give you feedback (mark as answer / up vote). thank you very much for the help !

Comment: It does not work but thanks for your help ! Is there a way to place this value of option.value in a variable? I have this in a different place and it works perfectly fine !

<dd class="values" data-bind="i18n: value"></dd>